# How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload, multi-upload

I have designed a simple form which allows the user to upload files to the server. Initially the form contains one 'browse' button. If the user wants to upload multiple files, he needs to click on the "Add More Files" button which adds another 'browse' button in the form. When the form is submitted, the file upload process is handled in 'upload.php' file. It works perfectly fine for uploading multiple files. Now I need to submit the form by using jQuery's '.submit()' and send a ajax ['.ajax()'] request to the 'upload.php' file to handle the file upload.

Here is my HTML form :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" />
    <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_more').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file' />");
    });
});
```

Here is the code for processing file upload :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
$target_path = "uploads/";
$ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
$target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file has been uploaded successfully <br />";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br />";
}
```

}

Any suggestions on how I should write my '.submit()' function will be really helpful.

Comment: I think you should use one of these process either you can submit or u can upload by ajax.. What you want its not clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery Similar question with possible solutions.

Comment: Either submit or upload, anything will work for me. But the file upload is the main priority.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution by using the following code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data Uploaded: "+data);
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Why don't you accept Kalai's answer as it pretty much covers everything you needed

Comment: Kalai's answer generates multiple errors. That is the reason why I did not accept. But I am glad and grateful to him as he tried to help.

Comment: Nice and simple solution, though in the code you posted above you  missed a  ;  at the end..

Comment: How can we get this browsed files(formData) in php?

Comment: @V.P You can access the submitted file related data in PHP by using the Superglobal variable $_FILES.

Comment: I have submitted the form via ajax. How can I access those data in php function.

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/c0bJbIVwRJ2G0Ubun_JTZQ.png . Is this the code that needs to be used in php function.(refer screenshot).

Comment: @V.P As I mentioned in my earlier comment, you can access the files related data using $_FILES. But if you have submitted other form elements you can access them using $_POST. You can use the codes from the screenshot you have referred if you think it serves your purpose.

Comment: @Rivnat I tried like this: Mage::log('ghj'.count($_POST['file']['name']), null, '107171.log'); But it logs result as 0. Please help.

Comment: @Rivnat  I tried like this too: Mage::log('ghj'.count($_FILES['file']['name']), null, '107171.log'); But it also logs result as 0. Please help.

Comment: @V.P Please try setting your input name as file like <input name='file[]' type='file' /> in your HTML from and see if it still counts 0?

Comment: @Rivnat This is my html form field: <input type="file" class="file" id="file" name="file[]" style="display: none;" onchange="fileSelected(this)" multiple="multiple">

Comment: @V.P I think it will be better if you post a question with detailed code and explain your queries there then several people can help you with your issues. It is a bit difficult to resolve issues in the comments section of a question.

Comment: @Rivnat Can you please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008669/save-multiple-browsed-file-to-a-folder

Answer (score 53):

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" />
    <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_more').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file'/>");
    });
});
```

for ajax upload

```
$('#upload').click(function() {
    var filedata = document.getElementsByName("file"),
            formdata = false;
    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
    }
    var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, img, reader, file;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        file = filedata.files[i];

        if (window.FileReader) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("file", file);
        }
    }
    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/path to upload/",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(res) {

            },       
            error: function(res) {

             }       
             });
            }
        });
```

PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded successfully <br />";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br />";
    }
}

/** 
    Edit: $target_path variable need to be reinitialized and should 
    be inside for loop to avoid appending previous file name to new one. 
*/
```

Please use the script above script for ajax upload. It will work

Comment: It shows "TypeError: document.getElementByName is not a function" for var filedata = document.getElementByName("file")

Comment: Sorry its a typo. replace document.getElementByName("file") with document.getElementsByName("file")

Comment: Still it shows "TypeError: filedata.files is undefined" for " var i = 0, len = filedata.files.length, img, reader, file; "

Comment: Better add 'multiple' attribute to file tag like <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple/> it will allow you to upload multiple files in a single file tag

Comment: @Kalai: its showing this error "showUploadedItem is not defined". What should I do to fix it?

Comment: That function i have not defined here, i.e., only for previewing the images. So comment that line

Comment: Its still reloading my page

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to add a progress bar for each file?

Comment: @kalai It shows an error "filedata.files is undefined" for var "filedata = document.getElementsByName("file");"

Comment: This code is obsolete now - I'm also getting errors - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'filedata.files.length')

Comment: change frome `formdata.append("file", file)` to `formdata.append("file[]", file)` works for me

Answer (score 4):

> Using this source code you can upload multiple file like google one by
>   one through ajax. Also you can see the uploading progress

**HTML**

```
 <input type="file" id="multiupload" name="uploadFiledd[]" multiple >
 <button type="button" id="upcvr" class="btn btn-primary">Start Upload</button>
 <div id="uploadsts"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script>

    function uploadajax(ttl,cl){

    var fileList = $('#multiupload').prop("files");
    $('#prog'+cl).removeClass('loading-prep').addClass('upload-image');

    var form_data =  "";

    form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("upload_image", fileList[cl]);


    var request = $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              async: true,
              data: form_data,
              type: 'POST', 
              xhr: function() {  
                  var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                  if(xhr.upload){ 
                  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
                      var percent = 0;
                      if (event.lengthComputable) {
                          percent = Math.ceil(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                      }
                      $('#prog'+cl).text(percent+'%') 
                   }, false);
                 }
                 return xhr;
              },
              success: function (res, status) {
                  if (status == 'success') {
                      percent = 0;
                      $('#prog' + cl).text('');
                      $('#prog' + cl).text('--Success: ');
                      if (cl < ttl) {
                          uploadajax(ttl, cl + 1);
                      } else {
                          alert('Done');
                      }
                  }
              },
              fail: function (res) {
                  alert('Failed');
              }    
          })
    }

    $('#upcvr').click(function(){
        var fileList = $('#multiupload').prop("files");
        $('#uploadsts').html('');
        var i;
        for ( i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            $('#uploadsts').append('<p class="upload-page">'+fileList[i].name+'<span class="loading-prep" id="prog'+i+'"></span></p>');
            if(i == fileList.length-1){
                uploadajax(fileList.length-1,0);
            }
         }
    });
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
upload.php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_image"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["upload_image"]["name"]);
```

Comment: You can upload image / file using jquery ajax and php like google upload. the file will upload one after another. Not all in one request...

Comment: this does nothing when I tried it, is there an error in the javascript?

Answer (score 3):

My solution

- Assuming that form id = "my_form_id"
- It detects the form ***method*** and form ***action*** from HTML

**jQuery** code

```
$('#my_form_id').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    var msg_error = 'An error has occured. Please try again later.';
    var msg_timeout = 'The server is not responding';
    var message = '';
    var form = $('#my_form_id');
    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            if (status==="timeout") {
                alert(msg_timeout);
            } else {
                alert(msg_error);
            }
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        timeout: 7000
    });
});
```