# jquery ajax mutliple photo upload from a tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a pretty basic jquery ajax photo upload for a page that I've created. I'm using exactly the same code as the tutorial, except I've made the few modifications explained later. The tutorial for creating it is here:
http://www.saaraan.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-with-progressbar-with-jquery-and-php

The problem I'm running into is I'm trying to convert the script to allow multiple uploads on a page. I have the page setup with multiple forms already, and the php action is ready to receive multiple photos, I'm just clueless when it comes to the jquery part. It declares myform with the id of UploadForm, but since I converted it, I now have the ids of UploadForm1, UploadForm2, UploadForm3, etc..

```
var myform          = $("#UploadForm");
```

There is a short way of doing the this in jquery I'm sure, but the only solution I can come up with is just repeating the jquery function as many times as I need with the ids hard-coded. Once someone shows me how to fix the UploadForm id problem, I'll be able to fix the progressbar, progressbox, statustxt, and submitbutton ids as well.

Comment: Please note that if you are using form data then you will run into compatability issues using this code as not all browsers use formdata. you would be better detecting if the browser returns false use an iframe to upload the file if not use formdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a class to each one and reference the class with `$('.ClassName')`. Then go through the collection with `.each(function(){})`.

Comment: Okay, excuse my ignorance, but it seems .each works similar to php's foreach loop?

Comment: Answered my own question. You put me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could allow for each photo to have an input element inside your form, and with a little JavaScript you could allow the user to add/remove rows in your form. Essentially, you are looking for multiple file upload. I've found something that might help:

[How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-php-using-jquery-and-ajax)