# Example of using Ajax to upload multiple files in Play framework 2.3.0 (Java)

Tags: java, ajax, playframework-2.0, multiple-file-upload

I am looking for an example of using Ajax to upload multiple files in Play java framework.

This is the HTML form:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="multiplefiles" multiple required>
    <button type="submit" id="button">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And this is the only thing I found in Play documentation:

```
public static Result upload() {
     File file = request().body().asRaw().asFile();
     return ok("File uploaded");
}
```

I don't know how to send the files via Ajax and how to split them in Play.

BTW, I was able to do it via the form action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: @CoryKlein Thanks. I am more concerned about the Play side code.

Comment: from the server side there is no different. you can use the form action