# ajax - how to upload multiple files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck and need your help - I have designed a simple form which allows the user to upload comment text and files to the server. When the form is submitted, the file upload process is handled in 'upload.php' file. It works perfectly fine for uploading only 1 file.

I would like my script to be able upload  multiple files with AJAX.

This is what I did so far -

HTML (part of it):

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />
<input type='file' name='file[]' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

    var $form = $(this);
    var file_data = $form.find('.file-field').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();       
    form_data.append('act', act);
    form_data.append('comment[text]',  $form.find('.comment-field').val());   
    form_data.append('comment[pageName]',  $form.find('.pagename-field').val());   

    form_data.append('file[]', file_data);



    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajax/addComment.php",

           dataType: 'text',  
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,  
           async: false,
           data: form_data,
           success: function(data)
           {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $('#commentsBox'+$form.find('.refid-field').val()).prepend(data);
                 $("form").reset(); 

           }

         });

    return false; 

    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload files using Ajax. You will have to have form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and submit the form using normal html request. To avoid the page refresh you can use iframe.

There are jquery plugins like https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ 
integrating with php you can solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This sample with progressbar:

The HTML :

### AJAX Image Upload

```
<form id="image_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type='file' name='file' maxlength='1' id="image1" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" /> <br />
    <input type='file' name='file' maxlength='1' id="image2" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" /> <br />
    <input type='file' name='file' maxlength='1'  id="image3" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" /> <br />


    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>


    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
    function _(elementID)
    {
        return document.getElementById(elementID);
    }
    function uploadFile()
    {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        var file = _("image1").files[0];
        if (file == 'undefined') {
            alert('file not selected');
            return false;
        }
        formdata.append("file[]", file);

        var file = _("image2").files[0];
        if (file != 'undefined') {

            formdata.append("file[]", file);
        }
        var file = _("image3").files[0];
        if (file != 'undefined') {

            formdata.append("file[]", file);
        }
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", myProgressHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", myCompleteHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("error", myErrorHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", myAbortHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }

    function myProgressHandler(event)
    {
        _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML =
                "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
        _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
    }
    function myCompleteHandler(event)
    {
        _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
        _("progressBar").value = 0;
    }
    function myErrorHandler(event)
    {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
    }
    function myAbortHandler(event)
    {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
    }
```

and php file "file_upload_parser.php":

```
<pre>
    <?php 

        print_r($_FILES);
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need 1 change - I don't know how many file will be uploaded. I need it to be array of files. can you please change your code?

<input type='file' name='file[]' />

Comment: I Change the answer, If you find your answer accept it.

Comment: you are still refering to "image1", "image2", "image3"...is it possible to do "for" or "each" loop and will scan array of files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for multiple image file upload.. 
 for html form..

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

And the PHP code will be..

```
<?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't sovle the ajax issue - how do I send the file to the server side/php file?