# Ajax - Upload multiple files in one request using multipart form-data

Tags: ajax, file-upload, multipartform-data

what is the best plugin to upload multiple files in one request using multi-part form-data in ajax?

I am trying to upload multiple files in one server call using ajax.

but could not find the plugin to satisfy the requirement.

any suggestions or working examples?

Comment: did you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax) ?

Comment: My application should work in ie9. The example you gave is using FormData which is IE 10+ support. So I am looking for a plugin.