# No file being uploaded while uploading multiple files using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, multifile-uploader

I am trying to upload multiple files with only 1 AJAX request. But I am facing some problems and they are:

***UPDATE***

- No file is being uploaded to the server
- <s>It seems to me that multiple AJAX requests are being made as AJAX is inside the for loop.</s>

How to sort these problems?

**HTML**

```
<!--<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->
    <input type="file" multiple name="uploadfile[]" id="uploadfile" />
<!--</form>-->
```

**JS**

```
$("#uploadfile").change(function(){
     //submit the form here  
    //$('#fileupload').submit();
    var files = $("#uploadfile")[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        //alert(files[i].name);
        var data = files[i].name;
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'mupld.php',
            data: data
        });
    }

//var files = $('#uploadfile').prop("files"); //files will be a FileList object.
//alert(files);
//var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; }); //names is an array of strings (file names)
```

});

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile'])){

    $errors= array();

    foreach($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$key]; 
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       

        //$query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";

        $desired_dir="storage";

        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }
            else{                                   // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         //mysql_query($query);         
        }
        else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `js` at Question does not appear to upload `File` object, but `File.name` `var data = files[i].name;`? `<!-- -->` is not valid comment in `javascript`.

Comment: Can you kindly make the corrections as I am not good at JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`js` at Question does not appear to upload `File` object, but `File.name` at `var data = files[i].name;` ? `<!-- -->` is not valid comment in `javascript`

Try using `FormData()`

```
$("#uploadfile").change(function() {
    var files = $("#fileupload")[0];
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "mupld.php",
            data: new FormData(files),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        });
});
```

Comment: And how should I process the data in PHP? Will it be the same like my PHP script?

Comment: I changed my JS accordingly with my PHP script but still no files are being uploaded.

Comment: @Ayan See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: @Ayan Are you receiving any errors at `js` or `php`?

Comment: Have you un-commented  `<form>` element?

Comment: Yes I did and added the action attribute as url in ajax.

Comment: @Ayan See updated post, `d` at `processData` should be uppercase

Comment: Yea I was doing with uppercase D only but with no use. You can see my the code here http://pastebin.com/hujcY02u

Comment: @Ayan You can verify that the files are uploaded by checking last request at `Network` tab at `devtools` following selecting files  https://jsfiddle.net/nu9674ds/

Comment: In the network tab it shows method as POST, file as mupld.php and domain as localhost, type as html, transfer as 0.00KB. Yet no files are being saved on the server.

Comment: I think the filesize is creating a problem because all file uploads below 1mb are being uploaded whereas I have set in my php script to allow file uploads below 2mb. How to change the upload limit?

Comment: @Ayan Try removing `click()`. Just tried using `php` at Question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax, and all files were uploaded

Comment: _"How to change the upload limit?"_ Increase the file size limit?

Comment: Yes something like that so that users can upload any sized files.

Comment: @Ayan Remove `if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }` at `php`

Comment: I tried but still only files below 2 mb are being uploaded.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size , http://pastebin.com/7e0MessM

Answer (score 0):

Use it

[AJAX File Upload plugin](https://github.com/davgothic/AjaxFileUpload/)

```
<pre>
    $("#uploadfile").change(function(){ 
    $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:'mupld.php',
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'uploadfile[]',
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{},
            success: function (data, status)
            {

            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {

            }
        }
    );
    });
</pre>
```

Comment: Can I later on add a radial progress bar with it?

Comment: https://github.com/davgothic/AjaxFileUpload/blob/master/demos/advanced.html