# How to upload multiple image with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, kohana

I have a website using the Kohana framework. I have a problem when I tried upload multiple image using AJAX. I tried with many methods but without success. I think the problem is in function `_save_images($image)` at line:

```
if ($file = Upload::save($image, NULL, $directory))
```

Because I tried `echo` this values but receive result like:

> Website not support width less than 900px on Computer

A function to save image with parameter `$image` is array list image.

In `ProductImage.php`:

```
protected function _save_images($image)
{
    $directory = DOCROOT.'uploads/';

    if ($file = Upload::save($image, NULL, $directory))
    {
        $filename = strtolower(Text::random('alnum', 20)).'.jpg';

        Image::factory($file)
            ->resize(200, 200, Image::AUTO)
            ->save($directory.$filename);

        // Delete the temporary file
        unlink($file);

        return $filename;
    }
}
```

And I have a function to upload multiple image.

```
public function action_create()
{
    $user = Auth_Jelly::instance()->get_user();  
    $iduser = $user->id;
    if($user->has_role('admin') || $user->check_permission($iduser,'CREATE_PRODUCT')==1){
    $this->auto_render = false;
    if(Request::$is_ajax)
    {
        $name_img = Security::xss_clean($_POST['name_img']);
        $type_img = Security::xss_clean($_POST['type_img']); 
        $size_img = Security::xss_clean($_POST['size_img']); 

        $new_array = array();
        foreach($name_img as $item){
            $new_array['name'][] = $item;
        }
        foreach($type_img as $item){
            $new_array['type'][] = $item;
        }
        foreach($size_img as $item){
            $new_array['size'][] = $item;
        }

        $files = $new_array;
        unset($new_array);
        $ilosc = count($files['name'])-1;
        for($i=0; $i<=$ilosc; $i++) {        
            $_FILES['image_list'.$i]['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['image_list'.$i]['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['image_list'.$i]['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
            $array_new[] = array(
                'name'=>$_FILES['image_list'.$i]['name'],
                'type'=>$_FILES['image_list'.$i]['type'],
                'error'=>0,
                'size'=>$_FILES['image_list'.$i]['size'],
                );
        }

        foreach ($array_new as $key => $value) {
            $this->_save_images($value);
            if($this->save_images($value)==FALSE){
                echo "Faild Upload";
            }else{
                echo "Upload Success";
            }
        }
    }
    }else{
     // Request::current()->redirect('admin/home/denied');  
    }
}
```

And in `ProductImage.js`:

```
$("#"+form).click(function(){   

var image_list = Array();
var imageFiles = document.getElementById("image_list"),
    filesLength = imageFiles.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
      image_list[i] = imageFiles.files[i].name;
    }


var myFileList = document.getElementById('image_list').files;
var file ;
var name_img= Array();
var type_img= Array();
var size_img= Array();
// loop through files
for (var i = 0; i < myFileList.length; i++) {

    // get item
    file = myFileList.item(i);
    //or
    file = myFileList[i];
    name_img[i]= file.name;
    type_img[i]= file.type;
    size_img[i]= file.size;
}


var local = window.location;
var val_content = tinyMCE.editors[0].getContent();
var language = $.trim($('#product-create-language option:selected').val()); 
var category = $.trim($('input[name=category]').val());
var status = $.trim($('input[name=createstatus]:checked').val());
var position = $.trim($('input[name=createposition]:checked').val());

var matches = [];
$(".addcheck:checked").each(function() {
    matches.push(this.value);
});
if(matches.length>0)
    matches=matches;
else
    matches=null;
if(validateSpace(title,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",titleinfo) && validateSpace(image,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",imageinfo) && validateSpace(imagebig,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",imagebiginfo) && validateSpace(imagemobile,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",imagemobileinfo) && validateSpace(keywords,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",keywordsinfo) && validateSpace(description,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",descriptioninfo) && validateSpace(date,"<img src='"+base_url+"themes/admin/images/false.png' alt='false'>",dateinfo)){
        var data = {name_img:name_img,type_img:type_img,size_img:size_img,category:category,mycolor: matches,language:language,title:$("#"+title).val(),image:$("#"+image).val(),imagebig:$("#"+imagebig).val(),imagemobile:$("#"+imagemobile).val(),fileupload:$("#"+fileupload).val(),price:$("#"+price).val(),pricesale:$("#"+pricesale).val(),idproduct:$("#"+idproduct).val(),color:$("#"+color).val(),packing:$("#"+packing).val(),cbmpsc:$("#"+cbmpsc).val(),size:$("#"+size).val(),container:$("#"+container).val(),excerpt:$("#"+excerpt).val(),content:val_content,keywords:$("#"+keywords).val(),description:$("#"+description).val(),date:$("#"+date).val(),status:status,position:position};
        $(".product-content-create-total").fadeOut(); // hidden div content field register // children div of div class //register-form-center\\
        $(".product-content-create").css("height","auto"); // set height/auto after hidden div class //register-form-center\\
        $(".product-content-create-alert").html(""); // remove text div alert register // parent div of div id //register-form-content\\
        $(".product-content-create-alert").css("margin-bottom","25px");
        $(".product-content-create-alert").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".product-content-create-alert").html('<img src="'+base_url+'themes/admin/images/loader.gif" alt="loader">');
        $.ajax({
        url: admin_url +"product/create",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);
        }
    });
}else{
    return false;
}
});
});
```

That seem many code, so, I hope anyone can be help me.

Updated:

Here my code of form include submit button:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form-product-create" method="post">
    <input type="file"  id="image_list" name="image_list[]" multiple>
    <input type="button" name="btnproductcreateclick" value=" " id="btn-product-create-click" style="margin-left:119px;" class="form-btn-create-click" />
</form>
```

Comment: where is your FormData object?

Comment: @madalinivascu, I updated my question include FormData object.

Comment: i still don't see it

Comment: I find all my code but don't have any code like: `var data= new FormData();`. Seem this line: `var data = {name_img:name_img....etc` in my code is `FormData()`

Comment: and there is your answer use FormData

Comment: I don't know. Can you explain more information? And my error in my code? How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: did you googled FormData out of interest to see what it does?

Comment: I research on Google. But I maintain old project, old person add `var data = {name_img:name_img....etc`. Have you any method to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input name="file[]" type="file" />
        <button class="add_more">Add More Files</button>
        <input type="button" value="Upload File" id="upload"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_more').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).before("<input name='file[]' type='file'/>");
    });
});
```

PHP

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded successfully <br />";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! <br />";
    }
}
```

Ajax

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data Uploaded: "+data);
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
})
```

Source : [How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

In your code error looks like near,

```
foreach ($array_new as $key => $value) {
        $this->_save_images($value);
        if($this->save_images($value)==FALSE){
            echo "Faild Upload";
        }else{
            echo "Upload Success";
        }
}
```

when you call `$this->_save_images($value);` you don't save file name for uploaded image. `$file_name = $this->_save_images($value);` and than save this `$file_name`,

```
foreach ($array_new as $key => $value) {
            $file_name= $this->_save_images($value);
            if($this->save_images($file_name)==FALSE){
                echo "Faild Upload";
            }else{
                echo "Upload Success";
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML form must be have the “method” attribute with the “post” value. Because the file will only send to the server when the value of the method attribute of the form is post.

```
<form method="post" name="multiple_upload_form" id="multiple_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_form_submit" value="1"/>
        <label>Choose Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple >
    <div class="uploading none">
        <label> </label>
        <img src="uploading.gif"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

[Demo](http://www.programmingtip.com/multiple-images-upload-using-jquery-ajax-php/)