# Upload files in an array differently in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have this html

```
<input type="file" name="[]" multiple />
```

Now I want to upload each of the files separately but I am really stuck.

```
$('input:file').on('change', function(){
    allFiles = $(this)[0].files;
    for(var i = 0; allFiles.length > i; i++){
        eachFile = allFiles[i];
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(eachFile),
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

But I don't seem to work. I use the above `ajax` request to upload files in an array but I want to upload them differently. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

This is not a duplicate to the supposed duplicate question. I want to upload multiple files separately to the server but the question marked wants to upload multiple files at once. I use my above code to upload multiple files to the server at once an it works fine. So why should I as what I already have a solution to?

Comment: why would you want to upload multiple files separately?

Comment: maybe what you are asking is handling each files separately on the server

Comment: maybe use - or get inspiration from - https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. I want the upload the files separately but the marked duplicate question want to upload multiple files at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this... Tested (in chrome) and working

```
$('input:file').on('change', function(){
    allFiles = $(this)[0].files;
    for(var i = 0; allFiles.length > i; i++){
        var eachFile = allFiles[i],
        fileData = new FormData();
        fileData.append('file', eachFile);
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "POST",
            datatype:'script',
            data: fileData,
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    }
})
```