# How to send multiple data using AJAX along with the Form Data

Tags: php, ajax

I have this `ajax` code to send form data to a `php` file called **upload.php**

**My Problem is:** I can pass the form-data without any problem, but i `i cannot pass another data with it`. Everytime I do that, `ajax` is not pasing data to `upload.php`

Here's my `ajax`:

```
    function upload(fileid, imgno) {
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var data = new FormData();
                    jQuery.each(jQuery('#' + fileid)[0].files, function (i, file) {
                        data.append('file-' + i, file);
                    });


                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'includes/upload.php',
                        dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: {
                            data: data,
                            imgno: imgno
                        },
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function (php_script_response) {
                            alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
```

**and is is my `upload.php`**

```
    if (isset($_FILES['file0'])) { //it doesn't pass this condition
      echo 'B';

    }
    $imageNO = $_POST['imgno']; //this gives undefined index.
```

**How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: Try using FormData object. See an accepted solution here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append any extra field to the formData object like so:

`formData.append(name, value);`

and then send it to server side using ajax:

`data: formData,`

Then fetch on the server side using `$_POST['']` OR `$_GET['']` whichever method you use

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending "file-0" by ajax, but in a condition (PHP) you are checking "file0". Run network monitor and see what the browser is really sending.