# Ajax Multiple Upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have seen tons of ways to do the same thing and some scripts just don't intertwine with each other from jQuery to plain JavaScript and ajax, quite the confusion.

Anyway I found this upload script that only uploads single files and I challenge myself to turn it into a multi file uploader and I am getting this little issue every time I try changing up few variables that I read about to parse my php script with this top lines below.

```
function uploadFile(){

var file = _("file").files[0]; //This line is the issue, changed it around still gave null errors

var formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("file1", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

and my HTML looks like this

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

I tried every variable to not give errors and yet I get object or variable and null errors.

### Edit

This is what I been working with and this is the part that Is giving issues, I have more functions but they are in different link with the output of the parsing php file to handle progress bar and error handling. this part below is what I have been switching up since yesterday afternoon without success. @EmielZuurbier I tried incoperating your addon and still error messages about uploadFile not being a variable etc.

```
   }

   function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", “plistingscript.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: I am currently reading the article to see which bits to take and in cooperate with my existing script to see if it works. soon i am done I will give the verdict here. thats alot.

Comment: @RachelGallen still got errors about uploadFile is not a variable then i make a var then it's another error. I got it as a function from the onclick on the submit input still errors

Comment: @jasmine.willis ensure all vars are declared properly in your code and assess your code for any syntax errors (if necessary, use an online checker if you're going blind on it - sometimes it's easy to miss something when you've been looking at it too long). After these basics, **take a break** before you go back and do a step-by-step

Comment: took a nap just woke, i think i was going paranoid being at this for more than 24 hours. back to reading more. i need this working tonight.

Comment: anyone got time to give some advice and help please? I am trying everything I am reading and this just keep failing.

Comment: Finally got it to parse the files over unto the php file. however, i can use vardump and json_encode to see the data from $_FILES but no matter how I write this foreach loop, I get a null response.

Answer (score 0):

The line `_("file").files[0]` won't do no good. I assume that `_` is a replacement for the `$` of jQuery. It would create a jQuery object with the elements found by the `"file"` query and look for the `files` property on that object, which is not there.

But the FormData part is good and you should keep using that. When combining `FormData` with a `<form>` element you can get all the data from the form instantly by using the form as an argument for `FormData`.

To allow multiple files to be upload on a single `<input type="file">` element, add the `multiple` attribute to allow for more than 1 file to be selected.

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" multiple><br>
  <input type="button" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

```
const form = document.getElementById('upload_form');

function onSubmit(event) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  fetch('plistingscript.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}

form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
```

Comment: Thanks @EmielZuurbier, still getting errors. I should show you the rest of my script. see below