# jquery ajax FormData file Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

Im getting a empty file response when sending the formData in ajax, It has a fileupload and some input fields. I get the response in input fields but in file upload its empty. See picture below for code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="attachments" class="control-label col-xs-1" style="padding: 0px 0px;">Add attachments</label>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="file" name="attachments[]" id="attachments" class="custom-file-input" accept="application/pdf" multiple>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" name="name_file" id="name_file">
</div>
```

```
$("#acpl_submit").on("submit", function() {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append("test", "test");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: URL,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data)
        {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP file, returning the POST data for checking.

```
public function save_accomp() {
    return response()->json(request()->all());
}
```

[image]

Comment: next time please post codes instead of pictures

Comment: Does this post provide the information you need ? [How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: Please post your HTML code too (the upload file part)

Comment: Posting the codes. sorry for the code image.

Comment: Please also post the php file processing the multiple uploaded files. Thanks

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: What is `request()`? Does the `all()` method even include uploaded files? If it does, what data format are they represented by and are they even serializable to JSON?

Comment: yes it includes all files. my problem is the file upload it doesnt send the file.

Comment: Uncomment the enctype, also - is acpl_submit a button or the form?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` and check what result that gets you, then we will know for sure that it does _not_ have anything to do with `request()->all()`